# How can I add a caption (watermark) to photo (not bitmap) when capturing through camera on Android and save to file?

Tags: android

How can I add a caption (watermark) to photo (not bitmap) when capturing through camera on Android and save to file?

Comment: why you mentioned as not bitmap. We can `convert the photo to bitmap`, right?
check this link: https://androidluckyguys.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/add-watermark-to-captured-image/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. U can create a function like this. Here we are drawing a watermark over your original bitmap.

```
 public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src, String watermark) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setTextSize(18);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(true);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, 20, 25, paint);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to draw a watermark view over the surface view of the camera output and take the bitmap of the parent view. And finally convert and save it as JPG file